# Can't access static files where php_flag engine off

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have a Laravel web application that allows people to upload their files to an `uploads` directory.
I want to allow any file types and names but disallow executing them (just static file upload/download) so I created a `.htaccess` file:

/public_html/uploads/.htaccess:

```
php_flag engine off
```

But when I try to access the stored files (e.g. /uploads/photo.jpg) , Laravel comes up with a `NotFoundHttpException`.
 If I put a `#` before the line, I can access files, but then php scripts execute.

And here is the Laravel's htaccess file

/public_html/uploads/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents($filename)` to get the contents of the file and then send the file as direct static download using an `application\octect-stream` header.

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($fullPathToFile);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
echo $fileContent;
```

Using Laravel, you could always use the built in method:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#file-downloads

For Reference:

```
$name = 'theFileName.txt'; 
// You can override the name of the downloaded file

$headers = ['Content-Type'=>'application/octet-stream',]; 
// Sends a header saying the type is binary and should be accepted as such

// Fires off PSR-7 compatible response from Laravel
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, doesn't it add extra overhead on server? because the php process should keep running until the client get last bit. 
And also on large files the php maximum execution time may be insufficient

Comment: While what you say is true @Webinan, you can use `set_time_limit(int)` around the area with the desired functionality. The overhead of sending a file is minimal using Laravel's built in helper. Apache will always execute PHP files that are requested through it unless PHP is switched off, or you send the file as binary content after first reading the file contents into a buffer.